# Editing a input type number with steps and displaying the value upto 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react component similar to this:

```
export default function App() {
const [minVal, setMinVal] = useState(-19.0);
const [maxVal, setMaxVal] = useState(17.65);
const steps = 0.25;
const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
 setMinVal(Number(minVal).toFixed(2));
 setMaxVal(Number(maxVal).toFixed(2));
 let avg = ((Number(minVal) + Number(maxVal)) / 2).toFixed(2);
 avg = Number(avg);
 setVal(avg);
}, [minVal, maxVal]);

const onMinValChange = (e) => {
  setMinVal(Number(e.target.value).toFixed(2));
};

const onMaxValChange = (e) => {
  setMaxVal(Number(e.target.value).toFixed(2));
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    <p> The min value is {minVal} </p>
    <p> The max value is {maxVal} </p>
    <p> The value is {val} </p>
    <label for="min">
      Min Value:
      <input
        type="number"
        min={minVal}
        max={maxVal}
        step={steps}
        value={minVal}
        id="min"
        onChange={onMinValChange}
      />
    </label>
    <label for="max">
      Max Value:
    <input
      type="number"
      min={minVal}
      max={maxVal}
      step={steps}
      value={maxVal}
      id="max"
      onChange={onMaxValChange}
    />
  </label>
</div>
)}
```

here I am unable to enter any desired value after the decimal using my keyboard. Please note that I can't change the 'step' value here. I also need to display the value upto 2 decimal places.
You can check [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-carson-47k6zf?file=/src/App.js:69-1388) as well to see how it is working currently.

Comment: You want to edit your input with keyboard? and that's not working, Am I understand correct? or problem statement is different

Comment: yes you understood correctly, I am able to edit the value it's just that I am not able to enter desired value after the decimal

Comment: is your goal to have any input after the decimal, or it should be like the divisible by your steps (can only add , 25 ,50,75 )?

Comment: @BijaySingh https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-noyce-vcc596?file=/src/App.js

Try this link, and let me know If this is same which you want or not?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you try to enter something in the decimal point, your `onMinValChange` and `max` functions will forcefully update the value to 2 decimal points, consequently making it impossible to update the decimal point after the second position UNLESS you select one of the decimal points, and directly replace that digit instead of inserting a new digit.

Therefore, the fix will be to remove all the `.toFixed(2)` for the setStates, but only add that in the UI.

Specifically, change `setMinVal(Number(minVal).toFixed(2));` to just `setMinVal(Number(minVal));`, and update your UI with

```html
<p> The min value is {minVal.toFixed(2)} </p>
```

Comment: I tried this approach and removed toFixed part from everywhere else and added it to the value attribute of input like this value={minVal.toFixed(2)} but it is still not working

Comment: @BijaySingh The final suggestion i made was about line 29 and 30, instead of `value={minVal.toFixed(2)}`

Answer (score 0):

Like I have seen you are updating 2 decimal points(toFixed(2)) when user change input box, instead of you can do update when user leave that input for that you can find onBlur event in react input box, I have update demo in below link you can follow the same

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-noyce-vcc596?file=/src/App.js

Let me know if you have any doubt or further query